# Jquery loop on Json data

Tags: jquery, json, loops

If user clicks on button A, a loop should run through the cat.json file and check if object- `(jobcategory)"Data2":"B" == (job)"DataB":"B"`, if yes then display - `(job)"DataA":"C"` and `(job)"DataB":"B"` in a div.

I've got Json Data as below.

File name: cat.json

```
{
    "jobcategory": [
        {"Data1":"A","Data2":"B"},
        {"Data3":"C","Data4":"D"}
    ],

    "job":[
        {"DataA":"C","DataB":"B"},
        {"DataC":"T","DataD":"E"}
    ]
}
```

myscript.json is as below

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.getJSON("cat.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data.jobcategory, function() {
            $("ul").append("<li><button>"+this['Data1']+"</button></li>");
        });
    });
});
```

It display "A" and "B" buttons okay on a page. Not sure how to display `"DataA":"C"` and `"DataB":"B"` in a div when user clicks on button "A".

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = $("<li><button>"+this['Data1']+"</button></li>");
$("ul").append(btn);
btn.click(function () {
  $(this).parent().append('<div>' + data.jobs['Data' + $(this).text()] + '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more efficient to use an actual javascript loop. jQuery loops are great for looping through DOM elements but not necessary for JSON. These functions should help lead you in the right direction.

```
function jsonToList (json) {
    jsonLen = json.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonLen; i++ ) {
        for (item in json[i]) {
          createLi(json[i][item]);
        }
    }
}

function createLi (text) {
    $("#list").append("<li><button>"+text+"</button></li>");
}
```

Heres a demo you can modify to fit your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/7KvZn/